# Using sum in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I'm learning mongo and I have this schema below and i would like some help defining a query:

I would like to get the sum of the "entregado" fields that match this code: 151001. In this case i would get this result = 38.

Do I need to change the schema or is easy to get a query for what i want?

```
{
  "_id": 101,
  "torre": 1,
  "standard": {
    "mamposteria": [
      {
        "codigo": 311017,
        "descripcion": "LADRILLO ARCILLA H-10",
        "cantidad": 1080,
        "um": "UN",
        "entregado": 1080,
        "fecha": new Date('June 10, 2013'),
        "vale": [1322]
      },
      {
        "codigo": 311021,
        "descripcion": "LADRILLO ARCILLA H-7",
        "cantidad": 200,
        "um": "UN",
        "entregado": 200,
        "fecha": new Date('June 10, 2013'),
        "vale": [1322]
      },
     {
        "codigo": 151001,
        "descripcion": "CEMENTO GRIS 50 KG",
        "cantidad": 17,
        "um": "KG",
        "entregado": 17,
        "fecha": new Date('June 10, 2013'),
        "vale": [1322]
      }                             
    ],
    "mortero": [
      // . . .
    ],
    "estructura":[
      // . . .
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This could be done using aggregation framework. You have a lot of subdocuments - whether to change your schema or not is not an easy to answer question without just the information that you provided. It's all very application/usage specific. If the aggregation query you are asking for is the main query that your app will be sending to DB then I would most probably try to change it. Read up more on aggregation here and try to do something yourself: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/ . Data modelling is also a good read: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

To get the count alone u don't need to modify your schema.

Just following the below steps can give you the count what u need. I will not give you the whole query to find the count. That makes u lazy..so will give steps to get the count...

> ```
> 1) use $unwind 2) use $match to find the value for code: 151001 3)    use $group to $sum the values present in entregado
> ```

This should give you the count.

If you need any other help pls contact me I will help